# coldfusion 9 variable undefined in session

Tags: coldfusion, undefined, coldfusion-9

I have a page that prints an array with some information to the screen from a session variable (session.stufailedarray). At the top of the page, there a link to export the information to excel. When I try this (in Firefox, IE and Chrome) it works fine. But users keep telling me that they're receiving an error message: "Element stufailarray is undefined is session". I know the variable is there because it just printed it to the screen and I can see it in the debugging. Why would this be happening and only sometimes?

Code that  generates error:

```
<cfset ind=0>
<cfset anArray=arrayNew(2)>
<cfloop array="#session.stufailarray#" index="k">
  <cfset ind+=1>
  <cfset session.failed=find("UPDATE FAILED: ", "#k#")>
  <cfset session.rrr=REFind("\d{9,9}", "#k#")>
  <cfset idno=mid("#k#", REFind("\d{9,9}", "#k#"), 9)>
  <cfset failed=mid("#k#", Refind("UPDATE FAILED: ", "#k#"), Len(#k#)-(Refind("UPDATE FAILED: ", "#k#")))>
  <cfset anArray[ind][1]=#idno#>
  <cfset anArray[ind][2]=#failed#>
</cfloop>

<!--- Set content type. --->
<cfcontent type="Application/vnd.ms-excel">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=load_status.xls">

<cfoutput>
  <table cols=2 border=1>
    <cfloop from="1" to ="#ArrayLen(anArray)#" index="row">
      <tr>
        <td>#anArray[row][1]#</td>
        <td>#anArray[row][2]#</td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </table>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I don't see where that code references `session.stufailedarray`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<!--- Set content type. --->
<cfset anArray=[]/>
<cfif isDefined(session.stufailedarray)>
    <cfset anArray=session.stufailedarray/>
</cfif>

<cfcontent type="Application/vnd.ms-excel">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=load_status.xls">

<cfoutput>
  <table cols=2 border=1>
    <cfloop from="1" to ="#ArrayLen(anArray)#" index="row">
      <tr>
        <td>#anArray[row][1]#</td>
        <td>#anArray[row][2]#</td>
      </tr>
    </cfloop>
  </table>
</cfoutput>
```

Make sure that you configured and enabled application session properly.
To use session variables, enable them in two places:

> ColdFusion Administrator The Application.cfc initialization code
>   This.sessionManagement variable or the active cfapplication tag.
>   ColdFusion Administrator, Application.cfc, and the cfapplication tag
>   also provide facilities for configuring session variable behavior,
>   including the variable time-out.

[Configuring and using session variables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html)

Comment: this prevents an error, but it doesn't solve the issue of the session variable being undefined

Comment: I agree, we need more details.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you have a variable called `session.stufailedarray`. However in the code that you posted (which generates the error), you have `session.stufailarray`. This is also the error message that you are getting.

```
"Element stufailarray is undefined is session"
```

Note that the set (available) variable, the failed is passed tense, which the error variable is in present tense.